# Jquery dynamic load dropdownlist

Tags: ajax, jquery, drop-down-menu, dynamic-data

I have a problem about dynamic load dropdownlist. I debuged my ashx, it do post the data. But dropdownlist have no value.

Here is my Aspx page

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() {
            $.post("ContentLoad.ashx", function(datas) {
            for(var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
                    var data = datas[i];
                    var option = $("<option value='"+data.Id  + "'>" +data.Title + "</option");
                    $("#ddlClassId").append(option);
                }
            },"json");
        });
</script>
```

In the html have a dropdownlist.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClassId" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

And here is my ashx code:

```
public class ContentLoad : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            BLL.ChannelManeger bll = new BLL.ChannelManeger();
            DataTable dt = bll.GetList(0, 0);
            Data[] datas = new Data[dt.Rows.Count];

            int i = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                string id = dr["Id"].ToString();
                int ClassLayer = int.Parse(dr["ClassLayer"].ToString());
                string title = dr["Title"].ToString().Trim();
                if (ClassLayer == 1)
                {
                    datas[i++] = new Data() { Id = Convert.ToInt32(id), Title = title };
                }
                else
                {
                    title = "├ " + title;
                    title = StringOfChar(ClassLayer - 1, "　") + title;
                    datas[i++] = new Data() { Id = Convert.ToInt32(id), Title = title };
                }
            }
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            context.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(datas));
        }

        public static string StringOfChar(int strLong, string str)
        {
            string ReturnStr = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < strLong; i++)
            {
                ReturnStr += str;
            }

            return ReturnStr;
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    class Data
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code there was a typo inside for loop and also since dropdown list is a server control, its id might change so you should not use `id` selector unless you use `ClientID` of the control. I have simplied your code using `$.each` loop take a look.

```
   $(function() {
       $.post("ContentLoad.ashx", function(datas) {
           var $ddl = $("select[id*=ddlClassId]");
           $.each(datas, function(){
             $ddl.append("<option value='"+this.Id  + "'>" +this.Title + "</option");
           });
        },"json");
    });
```

Comment: It works but after I selected a empty dropdownlist, it shows what I want. Besides that I debuged the ashx after I selected dropdownlist. And I want to know `var $ddl = $("select[id*=ddlClassId]");` meaning. I edited it to ` var $ddl = $("#ddlClassId");`. It works too. I want to know the differences. Thanks.+1

Comment: `$("select[id*=ddlClassId]");` this will find the `select` element whose `id` attribute contains 'ddlClassId` and `$("#ddlClassId");` will find any element whose `id` is `ddlClassId`. Since the select dropdown `id` is `ddlClassId` it worked in both the cases.

Comment: What I want is when the html load the dropdownlist could be filled. And what's more, when I post back the result, did not have value. It's always be null.

Comment: You mean the new `option` which are added cannot be posted?

Comment: The result shows in page, but I checked the page source code it's empty. So the posted value is null.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2965/discussion-between-justin-and-shankarsangoli)

Comment: Dynamically added elements are not visible in the page source code. You can use Firefox firebug plugin to see them or IE developer tool in Internet Explorer.

Comment: You can select the dynamically createdn option and then debug your server side code to make sure its posted.

Comment: select the dynamically createdn option? How to do that? I've no idea.

Comment: It's a form. After filled, the values will be posted.

Comment: Yes, on the page load you are making a ajax call and get the news options and appending it to the select box. Now when you will the values in the form, select a option and post the form. You should get the selected value on the server side.

Comment: Yes, of course. Will you please give some clues? I don't know how to get the selected value.

Comment: There is no need to write any code. There is a `select` box you have to select which ever `option` you want using `mouse` and then submit the form.

Comment: I just did what you talk about on server side. The server side get null value.

Comment: Do you really need `AutoPostBack="True"` on this dropdown?

Comment: I set `AutoPostBack="false"`. I know AutoPostBack effect.

Comment: In hope now when you select anything from the dropdown the page is not posting until you hit submit.

Comment: After I submit, the other values was posted except dropdown value.

Answer (score 1):

look at this line: `var data = data[i];`
it should be var `data = datas[i];`